# Row cannot be located for updating

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I'm trying to delete some rows from an events table using the following.

```
DECLARE @PRODUCTION_ID int = 13811

DELETE openquery(TEST, 
'SELECT p.id as production_id FROM EVENTS ev 
LEFT JOIN production_seasons ps ON ev.production_season_id = ps.id 
LEFT JOIN productions p ON ps.production_id = p.id')
where production_id = @PRODUCTION_ID
```

However, the query fails when events are returned i.e. when there is a non empty resultset. If the resultset is empty the query just returns `(0 row(s) affected)`.

The error I get is:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TEST" returned
>   message "Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been
>   changed since it was last read.".

I'm not sure what this means, any help appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason for you to do the delete with an `OPENQUERY`?, can't you delete the records directly?

Comment: The link is to a MySQL database. I don't think there is any other option?

Comment: I managed to solve this problem since MySQL will seem confused to which rows to delete if the table isn't specified i.e. `SELECT EV.*`. Adding an answer it case it helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above query was changed to this:

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(500)
SELECT  @TSQL = 
'DELETE OPENQUERY(TEST,''SELECT ev.* FROM EVENTS ev 
LEFT JOIN production_seasons ps ON ev.production_season_id = ps.id 
LEFT JOIN productions p ON ps.production_id = p.id WHERE p.id = ' + convert(varchar, @PRODUCTION_ID) + ''')'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

The important part is the `select ev.*` as it seems to make it specific to delete from the events table. [This page](http://www.perturb.org/display/743_MySQL_Delete_with_a_LEFT_JOIN.html) helped me to realise this.

Since you can't pass variables via openquery I had to make use of [one of these](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314520).